# Storing user profile data from multiple lookup tables. how?

Tags: database, database-design, social-networking

I have a user table which has about 50-ish pieces of data. Some of it is Religion, political party, Ethnicity, City, Favorite movies, etc. Each of these items are lookup values from either: Their own lookup table OR I have a common lookup table for the small items like gender, sex preference, etc. Even favorite movie is from a movie lookup table.

The question is i assume in the member table all these will be stored as IDs and not text? So first Q:
1) Should they or should they not have FKs to the lookup tables?
2) If we store IDs then to get the actual answer text like Id 6 in city table = new york, Id 10 in nationality table = American etc. for the actual output on the page ,how will it be done? Do we need to Select from each lookup table in the read mode to output the text value? This scares me because out of the 50 pieces of data about 40 of them are lookup based, so that means 40 different select on 40 tables on page read mode and again on edit mode for the user to edit the values.

How is this implemented in real world sites with detailed user profiles? (I have search and analytics on each value so I need to ID them)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the scope, but this sounds like a sync process - setup a weekly/daily/hourly process to resync extended user information into a master table with a foreign key to the "user"-related table (username, password, email, update stamps, etc...).

Comment: I am lost. This is profile data like say your facebook profile data but with 10x more fields and all lookup based so input can be restricted to verified values only.

Comment: What does verification of values matter to the question? I'm talking about denormalizing your data into a table that is easier to work with, relying on a sync process to run the complicated queries.

Answer (score 1):

What you've described is the big tradeoff between normalized DB design and more of a flat-table design:  the queries are a lot more complicated with the normalized design, which is sounds like you have.

I'd think that you'd be reading from the table a lot more than you'd be writing to it?  (How often does a person's religion, gender, city, etc. change?)  In this case, (only) if you're running into performance issues on the read end, you might maintain two representations of the table:  one extensible, normalized one like you have, and a plain-text, flat version that's fast and piece of cake to query and read.  When you update the record in the normalized one, you update the record in the flat one.